# Increase shutdown time of windows instance with gcloud cli

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I would like to run a shutdown script that waits potentially up to 5 minutes before really shutting down a windows instance.

I know how to run a shutdown script but not how to prevent GCP to kill the instance after a certain time. In [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/shutdownscript), it is mentioned that there is a (non reliable) limit of **90 seconds** before the instance is completely shut down by GCP.

Is it possible to increase that limit ?

Comment: I am not aware of a method to change the Google shutdown time for a VM instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately 90 seconds limit is something that will not be changed. There are several [feature requests](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35904817) for this, but unlikely that will be implemented soon.